# Is it possible to change End Point Url when moving to Beta to Production from Playstore?

Tags: android

I have published an APK to Beta release with some version name and version code pointing to UAT endpoint.Is there a way auto-change the endpoint URL when I am moving to production from beta with same version name and code.

Comment: As per the document, you can  not have the beta and production with same version code, it must be incremental. And when is comes to end point change, your question is not clear.

Comment: I have two different endpoint URLs for UAT and Production. If the app works well in beta I have to move the same build to production with production URL.

Comment: you can create the flavors where you can update the base url based on flavor type

Comment: But we need to update the version Code and name right for each flavour

Comment: Yes, you can not have 2 versions of APK on playstore with same version code